# audiojs progress-bar not working when audiojs loading twice

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, audiojs

Due to the requirement of my project i have to load audio.js twice. Both of these javascript exist in different folder.
If i use both of these the dynamic elements of the audio like progress bar and timer stop working and this happens only in fire fox and not in chrome.
Can anyone give me the pointer as to what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

**audio.js is a drop-in javascript library that allows HTML5’s  tag**

**and  firefox does not support mp3 files on audio tag**

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

**I will suggest dont use this player ,instead of this use flowplayer which will support all browser with video format too**

[Flowplayer](https://github.com/flowplayer/flash)